# What tools does ROS2 Galactic ROS-Base Install includes?

Tags: ros2

Which tools are installed using:

`sudo apt install ros-galactic-ros-base`

In the official tutorial (https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html, ROS-Base install) is written that the installation includes: Communication libraries, message packages, command-line tools. No GUI tools.
What is meant especially by command line TOOLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROS 2 command-line tools refer primarily to the [`ros2cli` package](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli) and common extensions. They are commonly used in the [ROS 2 tutorials](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials.html). Here's a list of some common command-line tools:

- `ros2 run` is used to execute programs from installed ROS packages.
- `ros2 param` allows you to interact with node parameters.
- `ros2 topic` helps you introspect information about active ROS topics.
- `ros2 launch` is used execute launch files.

For a more complete list of the installed extensions to `ros2cli`, you can simply run the `ros2` command in a terminal, e.g.

```
$ ros2
usage: ros2 [-h] [--use-python-default-buffering] Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage. ...

ros2 is an extensible command-line tool for ROS 2.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --use-python-default-buffering
                        Do not force line buffering in stdout and instead use the python default buffering, which might be affected by
                        PYTHONUNBUFFERED/-u and depends on whatever stdout is interactive or not

Commands:
  bag        Various rosbag related sub-commands
  component  Various component related sub-commands
  daemon     Various daemon related sub-commands
  doctor     Check ROS setup and other potential issues
  interface  Show information about ROS interfaces
  launch     Run a launch file
  node       Various node related sub-commands
  param      Various param related sub-commands
  pkg        Various package related sub-commands
  run        Run a package specific executable
  service    Various service related sub-commands
  test       Run a ROS2 launch test
  topic      Various topic related sub-commands
  wtf        Use `wtf` as alias to `doctor`

  Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage.
```